# Laravel Collection Group By Date (Hour, Day, Week,Month, )

Tags: php, date, datetime, group-by, php-carbon

I'm trying to group my data by date. Hour, Day, Week, Month.

For Example I have a data like this.

> [ { first_time: { date: "2017-06-22 09:49:33.000000", timezone_type:
>   3, timezone: "UTC" }, second_time: { date: "2017-06-22
>   09:50:09.000000", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC" },
>   differenceInSeconds: 36 }, { first_time: { date: "2017-06-22
>   09:50:35.000000", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC" }, second_time: {
>   date: "2017-06-22 11:51:52.000000", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC"
>   }, differenceInSeconds: 7277 }, { first_time: { date: "2017-06-22
>   11:54:57.000000", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC" }, second_time: {
>   date: "2017-06-22 11:57:17.000000", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC"
>   }, differenceInSeconds: 140 } ]

I want to group this data by hour.

How can I do that in collection ?

Thanks

Comment: With the [GroupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby) method

Comment: @apokryfos now I'm trying Group By but its giving error  $hourlyQuotes = $collection->groupBy(function($item) {
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h', $item['first_time'])->format('Y-m-d h');
        }); Error is Trailing data

Comment: The format you're giving it is wrong. I don't think you need to give it a format, you can do `Carbon::parse($item['first_time'])->...`